# Stepwise removal of elements from a list

Tags: python, list, element

I would like to run through a list and make sure it meets the certain criteria.  The list looks like this:

```py
mylist = ["dog", "a", "b", "-b", "cat", "-cat", "-a", "-dog"]
```

I would like to be able to go through this list and every time a "-" is encountered, that element is compared to the element before it.  If these two elements are the same (with the exception of the "-") both would be removed and the process would being again.  So it would end up going through looking like this:

```py
["dog", "a", "b", "-b", "cat", "-cat", "-a", "-dog"]
["dog", "a", "cat", "-cat", "-a", "-dog"]
["dog", "a", "-a", "-dog"]
["dog", "-dog"]
[]
```

Where the [] are the product that would be used moving forward (so the other stuff doesn't need to print or show up, it is just the process I imagine Python doing in order to get to the end).

If the list that was being compared did not meet the criteria for removal at some point, the operation could just stop.  So, for a list that looked like this:

```py
newlist = ["dog", "a", "b", "-a", "-b", "-dog"]
```

Since the first "-" that is encountered would be associated with an "a" but the preceding element is a "b"

I was trying to work through this with a for loop:

```py
lt4 = []
lt5 = []
for i in mylist:
    for j in i+1:
        if [j] == [j-1]:
            temp = i[-j:j+1]
            lt4.append(temp)
    lt5.append(lt4)
```

I realize that this is a crude attempt, and it is obviously not working; currently I am getting type errors for having integers with the variables for iterations in the loop.  Any help is always very appreciated.

Comment: Try printing variables wherever they might have changed or be about to change. And read the error message, it does tell you valuable information.

Comment: For example print the  value of i as the first statement below the for i loop. And print j below the for j statement

Comment: And if you have bitten off more than you can chew, try solving a smaller part of the too-big problem, get that working, add a little bit more of the too-big problem, get that working, etc.

Comment: Also you should search the python documentation for built-in functions like enumerate() and range()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved using a stack - or at least thinking the resulting list as a stack. (Try to research the subject ... is your friend)

```py
mylist = ["dog", "a", "b", "-b", "cat", "-cat", "-a", "-dog"]
# mylist = ["dog", "a", "b", "-a", "-b", "-dog"]

result=[]
for v in mylist:
  if len(result)>0 and v=='-'+result[-1]:
    result.pop()
  else:
    result.append(v)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly and I was able to adapt it to a few other circumstances very easily.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably opt for a recursive solution here.

Run over the list and look for any complimentary pairs. If you find one, then remove it and recursively call to remove any new values which may have appeared:

```
def remove_negatives(inputs):
    print(inputs)
    for i in range(0, len(inputs) - 1):
        prev = inputs[i]
        next = inputs[i + 1]
        if len(next) > 0 and next[0] == '-' and prev == next[1:]:
            return remove_negatives(inputs[:i] + inputs[i + 2:])
    return inputs


start_list = ["dog", "a", "b", "-b", "cat", "-cat", "-a", "-dog"]
end_list = remove_negatives(start_list)
```

prints:

```
['dog', 'a', 'b', '-b', 'cat', '-cat', '-a', '-dog']
['dog', 'a', 'cat', '-cat', '-a', '-dog']
['dog', 'a', '-a', '-dog']
['dog', '-dog']
[]
```